# Returning multiple values and default parameters in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function that takes in either 1 or 3 parameters, and returns either 1 or 3 values (based on parameters passed).

If 1 parameter is passed then the function uses default values for the other 2 arguments.
If 3 parameters are passed then it uses those values.

```
bool foo( bool x, int &y = 0, int &z = 0) {

x = true; y = y + 1; z = z + 2;

return x;

}
```

Is this possible in C++ or am I confused with Java functions.

Comment: Not possible with non-const references.

Comment: What's the point of the one-argument version?

Comment: How would you implement this in Java? Just out of curiosity, I don't think you can really implement this in Java, so there should be no confusion on that side...

Comment: in java what can be done easily is just making it static and whenever referenced. then it changes, but in c++ you can do it by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with two functions:

```
bool foo( bool x, int &y, int &z) {
    x = true; // this isn't really what it does, is it?
    y = y + 1; z = z + 2;
    return x;
}

bool foo(bool x)
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    return foo(x,a,b);
}
```

Comment: It's useless. `a` and `b` are useless, as its local to the overloaded function.

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm making the assumption that his function does something more complex than he is showing, and he doesn't want to duplicate that functionality.  In that case, you're right a and b are useless.  They are simply dummy values that allow the first version to be called from the second.

Answer (score 1):

Any function always returns **only 1 value**. Returning 2 or more values is not possible directly.

Indirectly, it happens when you pass parameters by reference. Since the two parameters `&y` and `&z` are passed by references, hence changes to them can be reflected back directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by passing by reference..

by doing so you are making a method that points to a memory location.
When that memory location is changed, then your value is changed.

Link
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr233.htm

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that this way. You can, however, overload that function with different number of parameters, and return, maybe, a `std::vector` or `std::list` with the results.

**EDIT**:

Being more sophisticated, you can use tuples for that:

```
typedef boost::tuple<bool,int,int> my_data_t;
my_data_t my_tuple(true, 1, 0);
```

then, you define your function like this:

```
bool foo( my_data_t & t)
{
    t.get<0>() = true;
    int& y = t.get<1>();
    y = y+1;
    int& z = t.get<2>();
    z = z+2;
    return t.get<0>();
}
```

and call it this way:

```
bool result = foo ( my_tuple );
```

then, out of the function, you'll see `my_tuple.get<1>()` (the corresponding to `y`) as 2 (1+1).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you can kind of return multiple values of different type using `boost::tuple`.

```
boost::tuple<bool, int, int> foo( bool x, int y = 0, int z = 0) {

    x = true; y = y + 1; z = z + 2;

    return boost::make_tuple(x, y, z);

}

int main() {
    boost::tuple<bool, int, int> result = foo(x, 1, 2);

    std::cout << boost::get<0>(result) << boost::get<1>(result) << boost::get<2>(result);
}
```

You could also use `boost::optional`, if you only want to return x, if only 1 parameter is passed.

Btw. `tuple` is available in C++11 too.